# How to Validate form without submitting it

Tags: javascript

I have a form that I want to validate before the form submits, when I press the Submit button. I know I am supposed to use `preventDefault` but I am not sure how to use it correctly:

```
function validateName() {
    var name = form.firstname.value;

    if (name == "") {
        document.getElementById("firstnameInvalid").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else if (/[0-9]/.test(name)) {
        document.getElementById("firstnameInvalid").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("firstnameInvalid").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}


<form name="form" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">

    <p>First Name:
        <input type="text" name="firstname" onblur="validateName()" onchange="validateName()" id="name" /> 
        <span id="firstnameInvalid" style="color:red; visibility:hidden"> Name is Invalid </span>
    </p>
```

Comment: Add a `return false; ` to your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the form by adding `return` statement to your validation code. `onsubmit` will stop the form submit when the function returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, returning false in your `onsubmit` callback will prevent the form from being submitted.

```
var form = document.getElementById( 'idgoeshere' );

form.onsubmit( function() {
    // validate here
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answer. You should explain what this code do and how it helps.

Comment: I am not trying to prevent from form from not submitting if its wrong, i am trying to stop it from submitting it all together, i am trying to add preventdefault to my submit button, becaus right now when i push submit i get "CANNOT post" message.

Answer (score 0):

your `validate()` must return a true or false value to it work with `onsubmit="return validate(this)"`

try something like

```
function validate(variable)
{
    if(condition) //add a condition to validate
    {
        return false; //if condition are met, return false and do not submit
    }
    //you can create more than one condition following this logic.
    return true; //if none of the conditions are met, he return true and submit
}
```